# Divergência entre versões do Delphi - DataSnap

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, datasnap

Banco de dados SQLServer a `proc` recebe um único parâmetro que é a matricula do cara e retorna o saldo.

Bem simples, mas aqui no Delphi XE8 com DataSnap só retorna zero e em outras plataformas como ASP.NET C# , Delphi 2010 a mesma `proc` é usada e retorna o valor correto.

**Comando SQL:**

```
SELECT SUM(CASE Fl_Credito WHEN 1 THEN Vl_Movimento ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE Fl_Credito WHEN 0 THEN Vl_Movimento ELSE 0 END)
    AS Vl_Saldo
    FROM tb_MOTOQUEIRO_MOVIMENTO
    WHERE NR_MATRICULA = @PIntMatricula
```

**Chamada no Delphi:**

```
  with DmBusca.cdsMotoSaldo do
  begin
    close;
    Params[0].AsInteger := StrToInt(edtMATRICULA.Text);
    Open;
    edtSaldo.Text := FloatToStr(FieldByName('vl_saldo').AsFloat);
  end;
```

Comment: Se você fizer o select direto, sem usar parâmetros, fixando o valor de NR_MATRICULA no select, oque ele retorna ?

Comment: Dento do delphi xe retorna sempre 0 mas como ja disse essa proc é de 2008 e funciona em outras plataformas perfeitamente inclusive no delphi 2010

Comment: Somente eu que achei o título da pergunta mal feito?

Comment: Vai retornar 0 mesmo se você chumbar o valor do parâmetro no commandtext? Já vi casos em que o "problema" estava nos Params[]